# SSIS sequence container conditional failure

Tags: ssis

I have the below sequence container that is failing whenever the get sharepoint DFT fails.
I have set the propogation of the get sharepoint DFT to false & also set the maximum error count of the container to 2

The data flow task is failing becuse of an error with the underlying connection that our IT department is investigating.

I want the sequence container to succeed if either of the tasks succeed. It should only fail if both tasks within it also fail -

[image: Failed sequence container]

Comment: Setting the Sequence container to have a max error of 2 should allow the sequence container to succeed.  You would also need to set the max error count on the package to 2 as well to get the whole package to succeed

Comment: Thanks Mark, changing the max error count has had no impact, the sequence container still fails

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach to get their without changing max error count:

1. Click on Get Sharepoint Data and go to the event handlers tab
2. On the event handlers tab, make sure on Error is selected in the dropdown and click in the window to create an on error event handler.
3. Open the variables window and click grid options
   [image]
4. Check system variables in the dialogue

[image]

5. Change the propagate variable to false
   [image]

Add some annotation in the package, because this is really unexpected behavior